# Spark SQL and MapType with string keys and any values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to define a Spark SQL schema that contains basically a `Map[String, Any]` field. The source of the data is JSON and the values are flexible.

I thought I could do something like this, but it fails:

```
scala> DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, DataType)
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.type
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
              DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, DataType)
```

Is there a way to create a `MapType` that can contain any value?

Comment: I can't prove it, but I sincerely doubt it. You can't have a `DataFrame` column that will hold an `Any`, so it is logical that you can't have a `MapType` that has `Any` as its value.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that might be the case, but I wanted to confirm that, since I'm new to Spark and I could be just missing something.