# Json creation from spark dataframe in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Currently,  we are converting a spark dataframe to JSON String to be sent to kafka.

In the process, we are doing toJSON twice which inserts \ for the inner json.

Snippet of the code:

```
val df=spark.sql("select * from dB.tbl")

val bus_dt="2022-09-23" 
case class kafkaMsg(busDate:String,msg:String)
```

Assuming my df has 2 columns as ID,STATUS, this will constitute the inner json of my kafka message.

JSON is created for msg and applied to case class.

```
val rdd=df.toJSON.rdd.map(msg=>kafkaMsg(busDate,msg))
```

Output at this step:

```
kafkaMsg(2022-09-23,{"id":1,"status":"active"})
```

Now, to send busDate and msg as JSON to kafka ,again a toJSON is applied.

```
val df1=spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toJSON
```

The output is:

```
{"busDate":"2022-09-23","msg":"{\"id\":1,\"status\":\"active\"}"}
```

The inner JSON is having \  which is not what the consumers are expecting.

Expected JSON:

```
{"busDate":"2022-09-23","msg":{"id":1,"status":"active"}}
```

How can I create this json without \ and send to kafka.

Please note the msg value varies and cannot be mapped to a schema.

Comment: What is unclear in the Spark documentation about writing dataframes to Kafka? You need a value column, not busDate or msg... Also, there's no need to convert to an RDD then back to a dataframe

Comment: I understand that kafka expects a value column and the value column that we want to send is a json string. That json string is having escape characters and also appears In the kafka topic and when downloaded to a file. The requirement is to have the json without the escape character  (\\) and I am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Comment: Also, how does your data "vary"? You've said you only have 2 columns in the dataframe, which definitely has a schema already

Comment: The above example says Assuming the dataframe has 2 columns  ...however actually in our system we deal with df having different number of columns.  And we need to dynamically convert those to the json for the msg key in the above expected format.

Comment: Also, to add we are having string Serializer for the value...

Comment: Spark must use Strings or ByteArray to write to Spark, yes. Did you look at the above link? Specifically, `"to_json(struct(*)) as value"`? That takes all columns of a dataframe to JSON string. Only if you have nested strings will there be escape characters

Comment: Yes, we are using toJson and due to nested strings we are seeing the escape characters. I tried using Jackson databind ti construct json and send that to kafka. It works with no escape characters, however date and timestamp fields are converted to some other format. Do you have any insights on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `msg` is escaped because it's already a string. So, you are toString-ing a String when you convert to JSON...

JSON can be represented as `Map[String, ?]`, so define a schema if your input data doesn't already have it.

Using PySpark as an example.

```py
scm = StructType([
    StructField('busDate', StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructField('msg', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), nullable=False)
])
sdf = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('2022-09-23', {"id":1,"status":"active"}),
], schema=scm)
```

Schema - Notice that `msg` is not a string, but a `Map[String, String]`. And no, you cannot have multiple value types - [Spark SQL and MapType with string keys and any values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574479/spark-sql-and-maptype-with-string-keys-and-any-values)

```
root
 |-- busDate: string (nullable = false)
 |-- msg: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

As JSON - You don't need Jackson, or hack around with RDDs...

```
kafkaDf = sdf.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) as value")
kafkaDf.show(truncate=False)
```

Not escaped...

Notice that the `id` type was converted. If that's not something you want, then you need to use `msg : StructType` rather than `MapType` and give `id : IntegerType`, for example. (This assumes all records in the dataframe are consistently typed, obviously)

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|{"busDate":"2022-09-23","msg":{"id":"1","status":"active"}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

You could also pull out the key (switched to using `spark.sql.functions`)

```py
kafkaDf = sdf.select(
    f.col("msg.id").cast("int").alias('key'), 
    f.to_json(f.struct('*')).alias('value')
)
kafkaDf.printSchema()
kafkaDf.show(truncate=False)
```

```
root
 |-- key: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|key|value                                                      |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"busDate":"2022-09-23","msg":{"id":"1","status":"active"}}|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you can use `kafkaDf.write.format("kafka")`, as normal

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to wrap string information in a single field, rather then key-value pairs, then your Kafka consumers would need to handle that on their own, such as double-deserializing both the record, then the inner string (JSON value).

Comment: Thank you very much for the above. However, my msg part cannot be mapped to a defined schema as we are dealing with multiple tables with multiple schemas. And also, cannot have all the columns as strings. The above example with only 2 fields in the msg part was just for illustration.

Comment: 1) MapType doesn't care about the number of columns, as long as keys are unique (which is a given in JSON). 2) It must have consistent value types. So, seems to me, you'll need to double-encode your JSON. Even Avro or Protobuf maps don't support differing map value types 3) You should separate each table, then, into their own self descriptive schemas, and not combine them

Comment: Your only other option with Structured Streaming is to convert the dataframe into a an RDD, then `.map` over that, manually parse/reformat it (using Jackson, as you'd mentioned), then `writeValueAsBytes` for some generic JsonObject. Then convert back into a dataframe with `StructType(StructField("value", BinaryType() ` schema, then send that

Comment: Or, just don't use Spark. Use Kafka Connect / Debezium, if your database supports it

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I have been able to generate the json using Jackson module.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer showing your solution